# Second and Third Largest values T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code.

I am interested in ColumnOfInterest. Right now, the below code will group C1/C2/C3 combination and output only the rows that has latest T2.Date...right?

```
SELECT  T1.C1,T1.C2,T1.C3
    ,T1.ColumnofInterest (First Top Value)
    ,T1.Date
    ,T2.Date
    ,MAX(T2.Date) AS DDate
    ,COUNT(1) AS GroupCount 
FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table2 T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
GROUP BY T1.C1,T1.C2,T1.C2
    ,T1.ColumnofInterest
    ,T1.Date
    ,T2.Date
HAVING (T2.Date BETWEEN DATEADD(DD,-365,T1.Date) AND T1.Date)
```

I want to get two more column that gives me ColumnOfInterest2 and ColumnofInterest3 which would have values for 2nd and 3rd latest T2.Date.

Is this possible?

I want to get these values which I will use later to update a table.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The following query gets the row with the latest t2 date:

```
select c1, c2, c3, ColumnOfInterest, t1date, t2date, GroupCount
from (SELECT T1.C1, T1.C2, T1.C3, T1.ColumnofInterest,
             T1.Date as t1date, T2.Date as t2date,
             row_number() over (partition by t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.c3 order by t2.date desc) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.c3) as GroupCount
      FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN
           Table2 T2
            ON T1.ID = T2.ID
    ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

It is hard to explain what your query does, but because it is grouping by the dates, the count is probably always 1.  This assigns a sequential number to each group (based on the `partition by` clause).  The most recent date gets a value of 1 (`order by t2.date desc`).

The following version gets the second and third dates on different rows:

```
select c1, c2, c3, ColumnOfInterest, t1date, t2date, GroupCount
from (SELECT T1.C1, T1.C2, T1.C3, T1.ColumnofInterest,
             T1.Date as t1date, T2.Date as t2date,
             row_number() over (partition by t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.c3 order by t2.date desc) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.c3) as GroupCount
      FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN
           Table2 T2
            ON T1.ID = T2.ID
    ) t
where seqnum in (1, 2, 3);
```

And this version puts them on the same row:

```
select c1, c2, c3, ColumnOfInterest, max(t1date), max(t2date), count(*) as GroupCount
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then ColumnofInterest end) as ColumnofInterest_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then ColumnofInterest end) as ColumnofInterest_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then ColumnofInterest end) as ColumnofInterest_3
from (SELECT T1.C1, T1.C2, T1.C3, T1.ColumnofInterest,
             T1.Date as t1date, T2.Date as t2date,
             row_number() over (partition by t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.c3 order by t2.date desc) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.c3) as GroupCount
      FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN
           Table2 T2
            ON T1.ID = T2.ID
    ) t
group by c1, 2, c3
```

Comment: why are you getting MAX of t1date in your third query? Also, what about HAVING clause?

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- I always figured the CTE with triple join is faster than the group by version -- but I never tested it.